# Warning: Illegal offset type in drupal_add_js() (line 4184 of C:\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\lfp\includes\common.inc)

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using D7. I am getting the above error when I created a js file with the code below and then included it in the .info file. What is wrong?

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.userLoginChanges = {
    attach: function(context) {
        $("#user-login-form").attr("placeholder", "Username");

    }
}
}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: Ignore this question: I realized the issue - In the info file I was writing scripts[all][] = filename, the same way you do it with css files. The correct syntax is scripts[] = filename.

Comment: No harm in putting that as an answer, could help someone in the future :)

Answer (score 6):

I realized the issue - In the info file I was writing scripts[all][] = filename, the same way you do it with css files. The correct syntax is scripts[] = filename.